# Powershell Script - Open Excel, Update External Data, Save as

Tags: excel, powershell, odbc, pivot

Is anyone able to help me with this script.

```
$file = 'C:\Scripts\Spreadsheet.xlsx'
$x1 = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$x1.Visible = $false
$enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yy")
$filename = 'C:\Scripts\Spreadsheet ' + $enddate + '.xlsx'
$wb = $x1.workbooks.Open($file)
$wb.refreshall
$wb.SaveAs($filename)
$wb.Close()
$x1.Quit()
Remove-Variable wb,x1
```

The workbook opens and updates its pivot table with external data through an ODBC connection. When you open the workbook manually it refreshes. When you open it with the script it just opens and does not refresh the data.

I have tried the following:

- Checking the checkbox *"Always use connection file"*
- Saving the password for the data source inside excel
- Disabling *"Enable background refresh"* and all the other refresh options
- Created a macro to automatically refresh the data source when the workbook opens

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This looks like `powershell` and not `vbscript`

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, my bad

Comment: Instead of `$wb.refreshall`, use [`$wb.UpdateLink()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-updatelink-method-excel)

Comment: using $wb.updatelinks() didnt throw up any errors but it didnt refresh/update the spreadsheet.

Comment: I managed to work it out I added () at the end of refresh all. So the new line was $wb.refreshall(), thank you for helping me get it sorted :)

Comment: @RossCopland Good to hear you sorted it. Consider adding as an answer with the corrected code and [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help out anyone else who runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 12):

Change

```
$wb.RefreshAll
```

to

```
$wb.RefreshAll()
```

Answer (score 2):

Additional considerations need to be made for Power Query refreshes.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7f73b446-9351-45f2-8114-2ac0f37a12e4/power-query-connections-not-refreshing-when-issued-workbookrefreshall-from-powershell?forum=powerquery

> One of the issues here is that BackgroundRefresh is enabled by default for Excel query tables (including ones created by Power Query), so when you call $wb.RefreshAll() it kicks off the refreshes and returns immediately while the refreshes are still running in the background.
> Blockquote