# RefreshAll() Inconsistent

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

Using PowerShell, I want to open several Excel workbooks, refresh all the links inside and then calculate the sheets so that when other users open them, they see the updated links and do not need to refresh the links. My script works, but not for all the sheets.

I discovered that having the sheet set to manual Calculate prevented it from Calculating on Save and Close, so I added script to change the Calculations to Automatic and then back to Manual, but it didn't work for one of the sheets. The only difference between that sheet and the others is that is it in a different folder, but the script is able to access the folder.

```
$Excel = new-object -comobject excel.application

$Excel.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
$Excel.visible = $False;

$wb = $Excel.workbooks.open("C:\Folder1\File1.xlsm") 

$xlAutomatic = -4105
$xlCalculationManual = -4135
$Excel.Calculation = $xlAutomatic

$wb.RefreshAll() #refresh links
$wb.close($true) #close and save

$wb = $Excel.workbooks.open("C:\Folder1\File2.xlsm")
$wb.RefreshAll() #refresh links
$wb.Calculate
$wb.close($true) #close and save

$wb = $Excel.workbooks.open("C:\Folder1\File3.xlsm")
$wb.RefreshAll() #refresh links
$wb.Calculate
$wb.close($true) #close and save

$wb = $Excel.workbooks.open("C:\Folder1\Folder2\File4.xlsm") # <-----File that is not updating
$wb.RefreshAll() #refresh links
$wb.Calculate
$wb.close($true) #close and save

$wb = $Excel.workbooks.open("C:\Folder1\File1.xlsm")
$wb.RefreshAll() #refresh links
$wb.Calculate

$Excel.Calculation = $xlCalculationManual

$wb.close($true) #close and save

$Excel.quit()

spps -n excel
```

I feel like I've got a lot of code that I don't need in here as I try to find what works.

Edit-

This helped me find the initial solution. I just want to understand why it only works for some of the files.
[Powershell Script - Open Excel, Update External Data, Save as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159268/powershell-script-open-excel-update-external-data-save-as)

Comment: Can you show what `File1` to `File4` looks like? obviously this is important for your question.

Comment: I added an edit to show the basic file structure.

Comment: Can you check in the file that does not work as intended if `Enable background refresh` is checked? If that is the case, uncheck it: On the Data tab, in the Connections group, click Refresh All, and then click Connection Properties. Uncheck **Enable background refresh** check box.

Comment: That option is grayed out. The links are vlookup links between workbooks in the same folders if that helps. In my reading on this issue I can across your suggestion, but that doesn't seem to be an option that I can change.I'm not completely familiar with it, but is that more for database connections or should it apply to cross wb links too?

Comment: When you open that workbook in PowerShell, check `$wb.connections` and see if `RefreshWithRefreshAll = True` or not.